# File not opening in C++

Tags: c++

What mistake am I doing that the file is not opening. The output screen shows file could not be opened. If I separately create ofstream and ifstream constructors than the file is written and read correctly. If I use fstream as below the file is not being created.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void main(){

    char num[10];
    fstream file;
    file.open("text.txt", ios::ate|ios::in|ios::out| ios::binary);
    if (!file)
    {
        cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    } // End if

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        cout << "Enter an integer " << endl;
        cin >> num[i];        //Input a number
        file.write((char*)num, sizeof(num));  //Function write to write data to file
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        file.read((char*)num, sizeof(num));  //Function to read data from the file
        cout << endl << num[i] << " ";
    }
    file.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: JFYI `void main()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Not all possible combinations of `ios` flags are also valid combinations, I guess yours aren't valid.

Comment: Does the file exist before you run this code? The combination of flags you've used requires that the file exists; it won't be created.

Comment: Code works for me if file exists (needed to add `#include <cstdlib>` for the `system` function).

Comment: Now i am using the following flags.
file.open("text.txt", ios::out | ios::out | ios::binary);
Still it's not working

Comment: Even using #include <cstdlib> is not solving my problem. It is not reading the data from the file correctly. Just creating the file and writing on it

Comment: This is starting to sound like a situation where the working directory for the program isn't what you expect so the program is trying to open `text.txt` in a directory that is different from where the fie you want to open is. Add the following to your program: `cout << getcwd(NULL, 0) << endl;` and see if that directory is where `text.txt` lives.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify `ios::trunc` or `ios::app` depending on whether you want the file to be rewritten or appended to, otherwise it won't be created if it doesn't exist:

```
file.open("text.txt", ios::trunc | ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
```

Note that `ios::ate` doesn't make sense in combination with `ios::trunc` because the file is truncated.

You may also take a look at [the table of correspondence between `ios` flags and equivalent `stdio` mode strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open). As you can see, the corresponding line of the table for your current code is

```
modestring openmode & ~ate  Action if file already exists   Action if file does not exist
"r+b"       binary|out|in        Read from start            Error
```

PS: And don't forget to change `void main()` to `int main()` because the former is undefined behavior.

**Update:** and yes, your whole writing and reading code is wrong. It should be rewritten as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
    cout << "Enter an integer " << endl;
    cin >> num[i];        //Input a number
}
// write the array once and outside of the loop
file.write((char*)num, sizeof(num)); 

// not necessary - just to ensure we read numbers in the next lines
memset(num, 0, sizeof(num)); 
// go to the beginning of the file
file.seekg(0);
// read the array once and outside of the loop
file.read((char*)num, sizeof(num));

for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
    cout << endl << num[i] << " ";
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7025671c2547bf5f)

Comment: Ok thank you but if still I use the above mentioned code as you suggested. It is still not reading the data from the file.It is just writing on the file.

Comment: @Rizvi [take a look at live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a330133d7de42e6)

Comment: @Rizvi ah yes, your whole code is wrong, see my update

Comment: Please let me know why are you using trunc flag. Trunc is use to delete the file content.
If i don't use trunc flag than file is not being created

Comment: @Rizvi If you don't want the file to be removed use `ios::app` as I wrote in the first sentence.

Comment: Ok but why are you using trunc flag?
Without this flag if my compile my program the file is not created

Comment: @Rizvi *I* am not using any flags. I am helping *you* to solve your problem. In my answer I linked a table of flags usage, have you looked at it? Also, *Without this flag if my compile my program the file is not created* - doesn't this answer your own question?

Comment: truncate flag: Any contents that existed in the file before it is open are discarded.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/
Before the file is open.It is not helping in creating the file

Comment: @Rizvi sorry, I can't help you anymore. The discussion is going in circle. One last time I give you a link. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open

Answer (score 0):

You should add 'ios::out' to your file.open

```
file.open("text.txt", ios::out);
```

You can also check if the file was opened easier by using

```
if (!file.is_open())
```

EDIT:

Probably the combination is not valid. Try to use

```
file.open("text.txt", ios::app|ios::out|ios::in|ios::binary);
```

instead

Comment: Ok thank you! But it then doesn't reads the data from the file

Comment: There is no `out` in `fstream`, so it looks in baseclasses and finally finds it in `ios_base`. In other words, `fstream::out` and `ios::out` are just different names for identical flags.

Comment: Then it's probably the combination try ios::app|ios::out|ios::in|ios::binary. It seems that ios::ate isn't valid with the others in combination

Comment: If i write 
file.open("text.txt",ios::out|ios::out|ios::binary);
Its writing on the file but not reading from it